# Call DataGridView CellClick

Tags: c#, datagridview

I just want to ask how can I call a datagridview_cellclick, In this code I have a switch case because I have a different buttons in my datagridview

Here is my code in datagridview_cellclick

```
    private void dgvFilter_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            try

            {
                switch (this.dgvFilter.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
                {

                    case "ColumnButtonField":
                        DataGridViewCell GridColumnLoc = this.dgvFilter.CurrentCell;
                        GridColumnLoc.Value = "..";
                        this.cmbField.Visible = true;
                        //cmbField.Items.Remove(this.txtName.Text);
                        iRowIdx = e.RowIndex;
                        Rectangle RECT = this.dgvFilter.GetCellDisplayRectangle(4,
                        GridColumnLoc.RowIndex, true);
                        cmbField.Top = RECT.Top;
                        cmbField.Left = RECT.Left;
                        cmbField.Width = RECT.Width;
                        break;

                    case "ColumnButtonRemove":
                        DataGridViewRow GridRowLoc2 = this.dgvFilter.CurrentRow;
                        this.dgvFilter.Rows.Remove(GridRowLoc2);
                        //GVGLCode.DataBind();
                        DataGridViewCell GridColumnLoc2 = this.dgvFilter.CurrentCell;
                        GridColumnLoc2.Value = "..";
                        iRowIdx = e.RowIndex;
                        Rectangle RECTRem = this.dgvFilter.GetCellDisplayRectangle(5,
                        GridColumnLoc2.RowIndex, true);

                        cmbField.Top = RECTRem.Top;
                        cmbField.Left = RECTRem.Left;
                        cmbField.Width = RECTRem.Width;
                        //GVGLCode.DataBind();
                        break;
        }
}
            catch { }
```

What I want is to call the event in the `case "ColumnButtonRemove":`

Is there a way where I can call that in selectedIndexChanged of a combobox? Or in a button? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `DataGridView`'s protected function `OnCellClick` :

```
OnCellClick(new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(columnIndex, rowIndex));
```

As it is a protected function, you will have to extend the `DataGridView` class to access it.

Anyway, a better pratice would be to create a function containing the `columnButtonRemove` `CellClick` code, so that you can call it wherever you want (in `CellClick` event, in `SelectedIndexChanged` event, ...).

Comment: What do you mean by extending the DataGridView class?

Comment: And I did plan on creating a function containing the columnbuttonremove code, but i don't know how to get it's column index without using this code "e.columnindex"

Comment: extending was meaning creating a child class.

Comment: To get the column index : `ColumnButtonRemove.Index`. Or : `dgvFilter.Columns["ColumnButtonRemove"].Index`.